# Style from resource dictionary only works at design time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have some styles for common controls defined in a separate file / resource dictionary. The file is referenced in App.xaml and gets loaded at startup.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <workbench:AppBootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Layout.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Resources/Layout.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="Heading1">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource Heading1FontSize}" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

At design time, it works perfectly. However, when the application runs, no style ever gets applied. What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the style for all your `label`? Do you want the style to apply to all of your `label` or just specific `label` controls?

If you want it applied to all types of `Label` control then you have to remove the `x:Key` attribute in your `Style` tag.

If you want it to be specific for each `Label` control then you have to define the `Style` property of each `Label Control` and point it to using the `key`.

More information can be found [here](http://wpftutorial.net/Styles.html)

**Update**

Try changing the `Source` to similar to this

```
pack://application:,,,/<AssemblyName>;component/Resources/Layout.xaml
```

Comment: I want to apply the style to specific labels. I'm doing this already with keys: `<Label Style={StaticResource Heading1} />`, however it's not working! **Edit:** Tried it also with DynamicResource, still not working...

Comment: Mh... I'm greeted with the error '"MyAssembly" is not referenced by this project'. I guess the location uri is only for external assemblies?

Comment: @Acrotygma No, try the clr-namespace

Comment: I figured something out. It did actually worked the whole time. I just added another property setter (Background) and that one got applied. The only property that does not work is FontSize, for whatever reason!

Comment: Where is `Heading1FontSize` defined? You need to define `Heading1FontSize` first before doing the `Style`. That's why it is not working.

Comment: Nono, this one is defined, I just omitted it because I thought it would be clear. Heading1FontSize is `<system:Double x:Key="Heading1FontSize">36</system:Double>`

Comment: No, what I mean is was the `Heading1FontSize` defined first before the `Style` for `Label`

Comment: Yes, it is. I think I tried practically everything.. Gosh, I feel like my brain is starting to fart.

Comment: Uhm... could it be that Label derives from TextBlock? Not that it's stated anywhere in the MSDN documentation, but I got another style that targets all TextBlocks. It's above the Label style definition, but when I remove it, everything magically starts working.

Comment: No, label doesn't inherit from TextBlock.